# Strange error when doing make on windows7

Tags: windows, makefile

Trying to run make on Windows7 with mingw but got cryptic error. I can't figure out what line in Makefile or what command caused the error.

```
C:\pkgs\C-TCC-0.02>make --debug > tmp.txt
syntax error at -e line 1, at EOF
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.
make: *** [blib\lib\C\\.exists] Error 255
```

The tmp.txt file

```
GNU Make 3.81
Copyright (C) 2006  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

This program built for i386-pc-mingw32
Reading makefiles...
Updating goal targets....
 File `makemakerdflt' does not exist.
   File `all' does not exist.
     File `pure_all' does not exist.
       File `config' does not exist.
         File `blibdirs' does not exist.
           File `blib\lib\C\\.exists' does not exist.
          Must remake target `blib\lib\C\\.exists'.
```

Any ideas would be appreciated.

**UPDATE1**

Here is the [Makefile](http://pastebin.com/raw/XAUE1ZQB)

Comment: The contents of your makefile would probably help someone help you.

Comment: Thanks @JJF, added the link to the makefile.

Comment: FYI links to code are discouraged here.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I should have used `dmake` instead of `make`.

Thanks to the tip from [Perl Monks](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=957110)